# Html paragraph number

Tags: html

how I can formate my text displayed in HTML like these:

```
1.1 cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk
    cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk
1.2 cnzxjknvjn jvnxcjkcxcx
    klczxkcnzxnclnxknckxnk
1.3 ....
```

and not like these:

```
       1.  cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk 
cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk
       2. cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk
```

Any ideas????

Comment: Put them in a `ol` ordered list?

Comment: How i can do these with double number

Comment: Try looking at the preview of the question next time before posting to make sure that the editor isn't misinterpreting your formatting ;)

Comment: @Haroldis: I'm not sure if you've seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635955/how-to-create-a-1-1-1-2-1-3-html-list

Comment: yes i seeing
but the format is   
1.1 cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk
    cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk
1.2 cnzxjknvjn jvnxcjkcxcx
    klczxkcnzxnclnxknckxnk
1.3 ....

and not like these:
   1.  cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk
   2. cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk

Answer (score 3):

Use an ordered list.

```
<ol>
    <li>cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
    <li>cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <li>cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
    <li>cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
</ol>
```

**Edit:**

If you don't care about IE6 the following will work =P

```
body {
    counter-reset:section;
}
ol {
    counter-increment:section;
    counter-reset:subsection;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment:subsection;
    content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.1 cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
1.2 cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
2.1 cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
2.2 cdashjkfhkdvfsdfjkvnjk cnzxjkvnkncjkvjkxcvbkcbvk </li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73vp5naf/

Comment: Ahh just saw your edit... well lack of formatting rather.

Comment: The paragraph number are in double 
and the text is separedet from the number

Comment: oops wrong JsFiddle. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

Browser's won't do decimals for you as far as I know.

You could use two ordered lists, one inside the other, and have the inner one with letters or roman numerals?

E.g.

```
<ol>
    <li>Part 1</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Child 1 of Part 1</li>
        <li>Child 2 of Part 1</li>
    </ol>
    <li>Part 2</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Child 1 of Part 2</li>
        <li>Child 2 of Part 2</li>
    </ol>
</ol>
```