# Text wrap for OL lists styled using CSS to be dotted lists, e.g. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc

Tags: html, css

I am working on the content for an online class I am developing and need to include college-specified course objectives.  Each week, I will have a page that will list the course objectives.  The objectives are listed using OL with CSS to create a list of the form UnitNum.1, UnitNum.2, etc.  I was able to get that working based on the advice at [Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1).

Here is a portion of my page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .dottedlist {
         counter-reset: dottedlistcnt;
      }
      .dottedlist li {
         list-style-type: none;
      }
      .dottedlist li::before {
         counter-increment: dottedlistcnt;
         content: "1." counter(dottedlistcnt) " ";
      }
      .dottedlist li {
         list-style-position: outside;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ol class="dottedlist">
      <li>Identify the major constraints that impact Project Management: scope, time and cost. </li>
      <li>Differentiate between IT projects and other kinds of projects: skills; turnover rates; uniqueness and complexity; visualization; requirements gathering; changing requirements; technology changes; software testing; and training.</li>
      <li>Elaborate essential functions of the Project Manager: manage project scope; manage human resources; manage communications; manage schedule; manage quality; and manage costs. </li>
      <li>Discuss the influence of organizational structure on Project Management effectiveness. </li>
    </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

The problem in the rendering are where the text wraps around for items 1.2 and 1.3 and is below the numbering, whereas I would like it to be aligned with the text above (each) line.

Additionally, does anyone know if there is a way I can parameterize the number 1 in .dottedlist li::before, so that on the other pages when I am dealing with other units I can simply add that in?

Comment: The wraps depends on screen size. On mine, they don't get wrapped. Make your `ol` e.g. 1000px wide to demonstrate it better :)

Comment: LMGTFY [oh it's already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1).

Comment: @zzzzBov: reread the question.

Comment: oh, he's suposed to put padding on the `li` elements. Then abs pos the counter within the padding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible since the `:before` is placed **inside** the `li`, not outside.

Consider JavaScript. Here's a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) based demo. You can copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 4503825</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('ol.dottedlist').each(function(i, ol) {
                    $ol = $(ol);
                    $ol.children('li').each(function(i, li) {
                        $li = $(li);
                        var level = '1.' + ($li.index() + 1);
                        $li.prepend('<span>' + level + '</span>');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            ol.dottedlist {
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            ol.dottedlist li span {
                margin: 0 5px 0 -25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="dottedlist">
            <li>Identify the major constraints that impact Project Management: scope, time and cost. </li>
            <li>Differentiate between IT projects and other kinds of projects: skills; turnover rates; uniqueness and complexity; visualization; requirements gathering; changing requirements; technology changes; software testing; and training.</li>
            <li>Elaborate essential functions of the Project Manager: manage project scope; manage human resources; manage communications; manage schedule; manage quality; and manage costs. </li>
            <li>Discuss the influence of organizational structure on Project Management effectiveness. </li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

As an extra bonus: it works on older browsers (IE6/7/etc) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure, exactly, of your use-case, but with the following mark-up:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>The first nested item</li>
            <li>The second nested Item</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>More nesting</li>
            <li>And even more...</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And CSS:

```
ol {
    list-style-position: outside;
    counter-reset: section;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    margin: 0 1em;
}
ol li {
    counter-increment: section;
}
ol li ol {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

ol li ol li {
    counter-increment: subsection;
}

ol li:before {
    content: "Section: " counter(section);
    width: 3em;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

ol li ol li:before {
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection);
}
```

It's certainly possible (though I'm not sure exactly what your question **is**), but here's a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Mbaag/)

---

**Edited** to address the text-wrapping issue that (somehow) passed me by the first time.

My approach to this is to give the containing `li` `position: relative;` and move it left by `1em`, then giving the `li:before` content `position: absolute;` and `left: -1em` (which is a bit unclean, to my tastes, but it works). The revised CSS is below:

```
ol {
    list-style-position: outside;
    counter-reset: section;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    margin: 0 1em;
}
ol li {
    counter-increment: section;
}
ol li ol {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

ol li ol li {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    position: relative;
    left: 1em;
}

ol li:before {
    content: "Section: " counter(section);
    width: 3em;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

ol li ol li:before {
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection);
    position: absolute;
    left: -2em;
    width: 2em;
}
```

And comes with a [revised JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Mbaag/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, starting with apologies for misreading the question: Sorry for that.

You can get the spacing you want by giving the list-items some padding, and positioning the counter within the padding.

You can parameterize the values by creating some id's that can be tied to different counter-reset values

```
#counter-1
{
  counter-reset: 1;
}
#counter-2
{
  counter-reset: 2;
}
etc...
```

It will take some work, but I believe it works.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, in CSS 2.0 and previous this isn't directly possible - you can't really mess with the numbering other than the start number.

CSS 3.0 might support it, but I'm not sure of browser support for CSS 3.0 and above.

Comment: -1 because it's wrong. CSS2 *can* do [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html). It's not supported in Internet Exploder though.