# Is it possible to create multi-level ordered list in HTML?

Tags: html

I want this:

```
1. Main
  1.1 sub1
  1.2 sub2
2. Main2
  2.1 sub3
```

is it possible to do this in HTML? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, at least in a modern browser:

```
li li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item) ". ";
}
```

(The `li li` is so it only does this after the first level.)

You'll probably need `counter-reset` as well.

Comment: Thanks, Ariel. I added some more for this to make it work.

Comment: But, we need to handle every level for this. A little bit annoying. Does HTML5 handle this better?

Answer (score 14):

This solution works for me:

```
/* hide original list counter */
ol li {display:block;} 
/* OR */
ol {list-style:none;}  

ol > li:first-child {counter-reset: item;} /* reset counter */
ol > li {counter-increment: item;} /* increment counter */
ol > li:before {content:counters(item, ".") ". "; font-weight:bold;} /* print counter */
```

Comment: I did a slight modification of your code fit it to my taste. It is located in another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1/25298818#25298818

Answer (score 0):

```css
body
{
    counter-reset:section;
}

h1
{
    counter-reset:subsection;
}

h1:before
{
    counter-increment:section;
    content:"Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2:before 
{
    counter-increment:subsection;
    content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
body
{
    counter-reset:section;
}
```

This is the sample of counter-increment and counter-reset.