# Custom <ol> numbering with section numbers

Tags: html, html-lists

I have several items in an outline each with similarly formatted section numbers.

Ex:

```
1.3.1
2.1.1
3.4.5
```

Is there a way to get my ordered lists to recognize "1.1.1" (and "2.1.1", etc) as the starting point?

So a list of releases would appear something like this:

```
1.1.1 mumbo jumbo
1.1.2 blah blah
1.1.3 something something
```

Using something like this as the HTML:

```
<ol start="1.1.1">
  <li>mumbo jumbo
  <li>blah blah
  <li>something something
</ol>
```

Is this possible in native HTML/CSS?  Obviously the HTML above doesn't work (the iterators revert back to 1, 2, 3).

Comment: I found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/161y6q54/)

You can do it using **CSS** `counter` property

**HTML**

```
<ol class="custom">
    <li>mumbo jumbo</li>
    <li>blah blah</li>
    <li>something something</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom {
    counter-reset: custom;
}
.custom li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.custom li::before {
    counter-increment: custom;
    content:"1.1." counter(custom)" ";
}
```

Read more about `counter` in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment)

and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_gen_counter-reset) is an example of `counter` from W3Schools.