# Custom Ordered List Content

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm hoping to mimic the ordered list formatting that I see in legislative statutes. One peculiarity is that you will sometimes see list such as this:

```
(a) yadda
(b) yadda
(b-1) yadda
(b-2) yadda
(c) yadda
(d) yadda
```

Comment: What's the question and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

you can use pseudo-element `::before` and [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: list, list2, list3;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: list;
}
li::before {
  content: "(" counter(list, lower-alpha)")";
  position: relative;
  left: -5px
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  counter-increment: list2 2
}
li:nth-last-child(2) {
  counter-increment: list3 3
}

li:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: "(" counter(list2, lower-alpha)"-1)";
}
li:nth-child(4)::before {
  content: "(" counter(list2, lower-alpha)"-2)";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some text here</li>
  <li>Some more text here..</li>
  <li>Oh yeah, here's some pretty text</li>
  <li>Some text here</li>
  <li>Some more text here..</li>
  <li>Oh yeah, here's some pretty text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an ordered list in HTML you have to use the tags `<ol>` to specified a ordered list and every item should be a `<li>` "list item".

```
<ol>
  <li>yadda</li>
  <li>yadda</li>
  <li>
    <ol>
      <li>yadda</li>
      <li>yadda</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>yadda</li>
</ol>
```

Please see an example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jruizx/pcs2mh4j/

You can have a look at this question:

[Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)