# How to order list which produce result that starts from 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3) with css and html

Tags: html, css

How to order list which produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, …) with css and html ?

So far getting output as,

[image]

for the below code,

HTML:

```
<ol>
<li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
<li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident:
    <ol>
        <li>sunt in culpa qui officia,</li>
        <li>deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    <ol>
        <li>Quis nostrud exercitation.</li>
        <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
            <ol>
                <li>
                    Duis aute irure dolor
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
  margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
```

But i need to get the result as,

[image]

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gha0cod3/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

Comment: it's not duplicate. the output format which i need is the different one

Comment: Hmm, you might be right @rinold the question looks to be the same but the answers provided are not what you are after.

Comment: The css is correct. But you need to set your list into a first list to have the number 1...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just modify your HTML to have all your list inside an li element as follow:

```
<ol>
  <li class="parent">
      /** Your HTML **/
  </li>
</ol>
```

And add the following css to hide the first numbering:

```
li.parent:before { content: ""; }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/q4482qoo/1/) you can find the demo.

Answer (score 3):

Just take out the extra dot `(". ")` from `li:before` in your CSS:

```
li:before {
content: counters(item, ".") ;
display: table-cell;
padding-right: 0.6em;    
}
```

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gha0cod3/1/)

Comment: But your output is not the same as the OP require.

Comment: i didn't mean that. I need the list to start from 1.1 not from 1

Answer (score 1):

```
Please Use this css 
----------



ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") "." counters(item, ".");
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;    
}

li li {
    margin: 0;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") "." counter(item);
}
    <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
        <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident:
            <ol>
                <li>sunt in culpa qui officia,</li>
                <li>deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam.
            <ol>
                <li>Quis nostrud exercitation.</li>
                <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut.
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            Duis aute irure dolor
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: i need to get the list in this format (1.1, 1.2, 1.3 )
not as (1.1, 2.2, 3.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use counters to do so!
[Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)
Here's another question on the same topic answered :D

Comment: i think none answered for the output which i required