# Changing the list style type to a specific format

Tags: html, html-lists

When I use this HTML code

```
<ol>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example
        <ol>
            <li>Example</li>
            <li>Example
                <ol>
                    <li>Example</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>Example</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Example</li>
</ol>
```

I will get this output:

[image]

How can I make my result look like this:

[image]

?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Bernhard I tried using all the values of list-style-type but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that resault you will have to use counters

```
OL { counter-reset: item }
LI { display: block }
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

Read [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) for more infos

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make it start with 0.0 instead of 1? Also the first level needs to be 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 instead of 1, 2, 3. How can I change this?

Comment: Use  < ol start=”″ >

Comment: `< ol start=”″ >` works well but not if I use your CSS code.

Comment: https://dev.opera.com/articles/automatic-numbering-with-css-counters/

Comment: at the end of the page you will find what fit to your case