# How to make nest numbering list in format ១.១ in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried to archive list style type of html and CSS just like below:

```
១.​ option1
​    ១.១.​ option1.1
    ១.២. option1.2
          ១.២.១. option 1.2.1
          ១.២.២.​ option 1.2.2
    ១.៣. option1.3
២. option2
៣. option3
៤. option4
```

Found in similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1), I came up with my html script like this:

```css
 ol {
   list-style: khmer;
  }
  ol { counter-reset: item }
  li{ display: block }
  li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
 <ol>
  <li>option1
   <ol>
    <li>option1.1</li>
    <li>option1.2
     <ol>
      <li>option 1.2.1</li>
      <li>option 1.2.2</li>
     </ol>
    </li>
    <li>option1.3</li>
   </ol>
  </li>
  <li>option2</li>
  <li>option3</li>
  <li>option4</li>
 </ol>
```

From above, the numbering is fine, however my list style at `list-style: khmer` won't applied as I want them to be `១.១,​ ១.២` like so.

Should any idea to my html code to make it working as I wish above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the list style type as an image, so as to pick exactly what you want

list-style-image: url("img/imageName");

Comment: how come I have every different image for every list style? is it possible?