# sublist numbering in asciidoc

Tags: text-formatting, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I need to display a list with this exact format:

`1. First item
  1.1. Subitem
    1.1.1. Sub-subitem
    1.1.2. Sub-subitem
  1.2. Subitem
2. Second item
...`

Is there a way to achieve this using asciidoc?

The closer way I found is using horizontal labeled lists, but the rendering differs from a normal numbered list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want CSS to do the Job of numbering, you an apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1) to Asciidoctor

```
++++
<style>
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol > li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li ol > li {
  margin: 0;
}

li ol > li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}
</style>
++++

. First item
.. Subitem
... Sub-subitem
... Sub-subitem
.. Subitem
. Second item
```

Will produce

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is for [PDF](https://gist.github.com/theaspect/642b61f881a35bc41b9c3c4c0fe37a93)

Put this file into document folder and run `asciidoctor-pdf -r ./numbers.rb example.adoc`

Answer (score -1):

Closer solution I found so far:

```
{empty}1. First item +
{nbsp}{nbsp}1.1. Subitem +
{nbsp}{nbsp}{nbsp}{nbsp}1.1.1. Sub-subitem +
{nbsp}{nbsp}{nbsp}{nbsp}1.1.2. Sub-subitem +
{nbsp}{nbsp}1.2. Subitem +
{empty}2. Second item +
...
```

Which renders as:

```
1. First item
  1.1. Subitem
    1.1.1. Sub-subitem
    1.1.2. Sub-subitem
  1.2 Subitem
2. Second item
...
```