# Formatting deep lists in markdown

Tags: markdown

I want to compose a list with the following format:

```
.1 - Lorem

    .1.1 - Inside Lorem

        .1.1.1 - Inside Inside lorem 

.2 - Lorem
```

And so on, but 8 whitespaces / 2 tabs are rendered as comments/code blocks, which makes .1.1.1 messy. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the standard ordered list syntax at every level, or Markdown processors do not recognize that the indented content represents a list item

So, you markup needs to look like:

```
1.  Lorem

    1.  Inside Lorem

        1.  Inside Inside lorem

2. Lorem
```

Then, to get the `1.1` and `1.1.1` numbering, you need to apply CSS to achieve that. See the answer for [Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

If you really need the hyphen between the number and the list item's text, you would also include that in the CSS:

```css
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " - "; counter-increment: item }
```