# Formatting ordered list in certain way

Tags: html

I have a HTML that produces an ordered list for me.

```
<ol>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4, holds some nested elements
        <ol>
            <li>Nested Element 1</li>
            <li>Nested Element 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The code above outputs it this way:

```
1. Element 1
2. Element 2
3. Element 3
4. Element 4, holds some nested elements
    1. Nested Element 1
    2. Nested Element 2
```

I'm trying to make it look it this way:

```
1. Element 1
2. Element 2
3. Element 3
4. Element 4, holds some nested elements
    4.1. Nested Element 1
    4.2. Nested Element 2
```

I've actually managed to solve it using the solution here:
[Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1)

and as I'm pretty new to HTML, I'm wondering if there's a way to solve it without using the CSS styles?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly done using CSS. The only parameters that can relate to this are `type` which is a basic version of CSS `list-style-type`, but the CSS one gives you a lot more options to customize this. You can also use `start` which specifies the starting number for the ordered list and `reversed` to reverse the list.

Comment: Is there any way the start can be set to float number so the starting number is for example 4.1? @Mihail

Comment: Hello @chileano you'd have to modify the first level of the list, but it's strange that you should start on 4.1, 4.1 should be a child element of 4.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section, ".") ". "; 
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 4, holds some nested elements
        <ol>
            <li>Nested Element 1</li>
            <li>Nested Element 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

See this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters