# HTML list with custom decimal numbers using value of li

Tags: html, css, list

I need to display a list like this:

```
1.      something ......
        aligned like this
1.1.    next something
1.1.1.  next
2.      something
3.      next something
```

As shown above,I want to list the items with custom numbers (from php code) and proper alignment

Here is what I've tried

```
<ol>
<li value="1">something<br/>aligned like this</li>
<li value="1.1">next something</li>
<li value="1.1.1">next</li>
<li value="2">something</li>
<li value="3">next something</li>
</ol>
```

But I'm not getting whole numbers only and no decimal points. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You can specify only integers for the LI value attribute to begin with - this does not take any “decimals.” The proper way to do this, would be to use _nested_ lists, when you want multiple _levels_ of hierarchy, and then to use CSS generated content to display the counter value.

Comment: I think you can do it with recursivity loop who's concatenating but you need to set a variable for depth.

Comment: @mplungjan the question says *I want to list the items with custom numbers (from php code)* <-- **custom numbers**

Comment: So not a [dupe of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1) ?

Comment: @mplungjan not really since that one will create a well structured list with counters (they will follow an incrementation logic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `attr()` with `content` and a table layout for the alignment

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

li:before {
  content: attr(value)".";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li value="1">something<br/>aligned like this</li>
  <li value="1.1">next something</li>
  <li value="1.1.1">next</li>
  <li value="2">something</li>
  <li value="3">next something</li>
</ol>
```