# Numbered List in a `TOC` Class by Python Markdown

Tags: python, html, css, markdown, python-markdown

I generate an HTML document using [Python Markdown](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown).
The *Table of Content* is embedded inside a `toc` class.

I would like the list to be numbers:

```
1. Subject 001
1.1. Sub Subject 001
1.2. Sub Subject 002
2. Subject 002
2.1. Sub Subject 001
2.2. Sub Subject 002
2.2.1. Sub Sub Subject 001
2.2.2. Sub Sub Subject 002
3. Subject 003
3.1. Sub Subject 001
3.2. Sub Subject 002
```

So it basically needs to take into accounting the nesting `ul` and `li` elements.

I looked at [Can ordered list produce result that looks like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...) with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195)
I came up with:

```
.toc ul { counter-reset: outItem; list-style: none }
.toc ul > li{ counter-reset: nestedItem }
.toc ul > li:before { content: counters(outItem, ".") ". "; counter-increment: outItem; margin-left: -2em; }
```

Yet I'm not sure it will support any number of nesting.
Is there a more correct to do so?

Comment: Does it work? If not, post a more complete set of source and state how it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kevin, It worked on my simple test case. Yet I'm not sure even what I did or on the scope of the counters hence I'd be happy for an expert solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution so far:

```
.toc ul { counter-reset: ulItem; list-style: none }
.toc ul > li:before { content: counters(ulItem, ".") ". "; counter-increment: ulItem; margin-left: -2em; }
```