# Customizing Obsidian's ordered lists with decimals

Tags: css, obsidian

I’m trying to set, through css snippets, ordered lists with decimals on OBSIDIAN, e.g…

```
1. Item 1
2. Item 2 
   2.1. Sub Item A
   2.2. Sub Item B
         2.2.1. Sub-Sub Item
```

Following [this CSS approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098195/can-ordered-list-produce-result-that-looks-like-1-1-1-2-1-3-instead-of-just-1/4098296#4098296) mentioned in another thread, I’ve created a snippet with the following pieces of code:

```
span.cm-formatting-list-ol.cm-list-1 {
  counter-reset: item !important; 
  }

span.cm-formatting-list-ol.cm-list-2:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item 
  }

span.cm-formatting-list-ol.cm-list-3:before { 
  content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item 
  }
```

Unfortunately, it’s doesn’t properly work. I get the following result:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't understand your comment. My question has a clearly formatted piece of code.

Comment: But it's not a [mcve] it's just a small snippet of CSS. Where is the HTML?

Comment: @Paulie_D As you can see by the thread's title and tag, it's a question related to Obsidian. People who uses Obsidian will know the further details. Thanks!