# Create an unordered nested list that starts at 1.2.1

Tags: html, css

I have have a nested unordered list.

I want the list to start at "1.2.1,1.2.2 ...".

Please see attached fiddle.

Desired outcome is:

[image]

```css
   OL { counter-reset: item; padding-left: 10px; }
   LI { display: block }
   LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   OL { counter-reset: item; padding-left: 10px; }
   LI { display: block }
   LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ol>
  <li>three
  <ol>
   <li>three.one</li>
   <li>three.two
    <ol>
     <li>three.two.one</li>
     <li>three.two.two</li>
    </ol>
      </li>
   </ol>
   </li>  
  </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635955/how-to-create-a-1-1-1-2-1-3-html-list found answer here, closing thanks!

Comment: why does it have to be an unordered list? do you not have access to the HTML?

Comment: FYI: _"I have have a nested unordered list"_ - no you don't, you have _ordered_ lists, that's what the "o" in `ol` stands for after all. An *u*nordered list is `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

use the  tag Instead

`````
 <head>
  <style>
   OL { counter-reset: item; padding-left: 10px; }
   LI { display: block }
   LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ul>
  <li>three
  <ul>
   <li>three.one</li>
   <li>three.two
    <ul>
     <li>three.two.one</li>
     <li>three.two.two</li>
    </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </li>  
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>````
`````